# Creating application/library connection diagram (overlapping tikz elements)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-arrows

[I'm using an existing `tikz` example to create a flow chart](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/) of sorts, showing how applications and libraries communicate with each other in a software project. For example, the following image depicts two applications (ie: peers) communicating directly with each other:

[image]

What I would like to do with `tikz` is to create a new type of element which consists of a square element with another square inside of it. I would use this to depict something similar to the above, but it implies that "Process A" requires the use of "Library B_API" to talk to "Process B".

[image]

How would I accomplish this with `tikz`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}

\tikzstyle{application} = [rectangle, fill=blue!30, text centered, text width=3cm, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=4cm]
\tikzstyle{library} = [rectangle, fill=green!50, text centered, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, text width=2cm]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]

\node[application, label={[yshift=-14mm]Process A}] (AppA) at (0,0) {};
\node[application] (AppB) at (5,0) {Process B};
\node[library] (LibB) at (0,-.5) {Library B\_API};

\draw[<->,>=latex] (LibB.east) -- ($(LibB.east)+(1,0)$) -- ($(AppB.west)-(.5,0)$) -- (AppB.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might consider using `\tikzset` in favor of `\tikzstyle`, see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/13304)

Comment: Also, your arrow is not going straight up. You can simply write `\draw[<->,>=latex] (LibB.east) -| ($(AppA)!.5!(AppB)$) -- (AppB.west);`, this way the L shape will be exactly in the middle of the two blue rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a nice exercise: an empty node with an inner labelled label.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[external/.style={fill=blue!40, minimum size=3cm},
    internal/.style={fill=green!30, text width=1.5cm, 
          minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=2cm, align=center}]

\node[external, label={[internal, label=above:Process A, name=api, 
          yshift=.5cm, anchor=south]270:{Library\\ B\_API}}] (A) {};
\node[external, right= of A] (B) {Process B};
\draw[<->] (api.east)--++(0:1cm)|- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]